# Conditional Probability of the null hypothesis given the rejection region

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, bayesian, hypothesis-testing

let $X  \sim Bin(10,p)$

We would like to test the following hypotheses:

$H_{0}: p=0.5 $ vs $H_{1} : p=0.3$

The Statistic $T(x)$ is defined as $T(x)=x$ and the critical (rejection) region is  $R=\{x:T(x)\le4\}$

I want to calculate the conditional probability of the null hypothesis given $T(x)\in R $

That is : $P(H_{0}\mid  T(x)\in R)$

**My first solution is:** $P(H_{0}\mid  T(x)\in R)=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+(1-\beta)}$

**My second solution** (according to Bayesian hypothesis):

$P(H_{0}\mid  T(x)\in R) = P(H_{0})*L(H_{0}\mid T(x)\in R)$ , which is equal to :

$P(H_{0}\mid  T(x)\in R) = P(H_{0})*P(T(x)\in R\mid H_{0})$

$P(T(x)\in R\mid H_{0})= P_{H_{0}}(X\le4)=0.37695=\alpha$

while $P(H_{0})$ equal to :

$ P(H_{0})= P(H_{0}\mid T(x)\notin R) + P(H_{0}\mid T(x)\in R)=\frac{1-\alpha}{\beta} +\frac{\alpha}{1-\beta} $

Thus: $P(H_{0}\mid  T(x)\in R)=(\frac{1-\alpha}{\beta} +\frac{\alpha}{1-\beta})*\alpha$

**Which of the above solutions is correct ?**

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question at CrossValidated (where it is also being recognised as not making sense)

Comment: Either of you could have added the link to the CV post:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/643698/conditional-probability-of-the-null-hypothesis-given-the-rejection-region

Comment: I can see that you edited your post to say $\Pr[H_0 \mid T(x) \in R] = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+(1-\beta)}$ but you still have not **explained** where this calculation comes from.  If you cannot explain your reasoning I will vote to close your question.

Answer (score 0):

None of this makes any sense.  The frequentist would say $\Pr[H_0]$ is not well-defined because $\Pr[p = 0.5]$ is not a statement about a random variable; and the Bayesian would protest that you have not specified a suitable prior distribution for $p$, and the computation cannot be performed until you do.

You also do not explain how you reason $$\Pr[H_0 \mid T(x) \in R] = \frac{\alpha}{1-\beta}.$$  Again, the frequentist will tell you this is nonsensical because $p$ is a *parameter*:  it is fixed, and does not change from experiment to experiment.  That it is unknown to us does not make it a random variable.  The Bayesian would tell you that
$$\Pr[H_0 \mid T(x) \in R] = \Pr[p = 0.5 \mid X \le 4] = \frac{\Pr[X \le 4 \mid p = 0.5]\Pr[p = 0.5]}{\Pr[X \le 4]}$$
and could reasonably interpret your hypothesis to imply that the prior on $p$ is a location-scale transformed Bernoulli with hyperparameter $\theta$; e.g.
$$\Pr[p = 0.5] = 1-\theta, \quad \Pr[p = 0.3] = \theta$$
hence $$\begin{align}
\Pr[X \le 4] &= \Pr[X \le 4 \mid p = 0.5] \Pr[p = 0.5] + \Pr[X \le 4 \mid p = 0.3] \Pr[p = 0.3] \\
&= \alpha (1 - \theta) + (1 - \beta) \theta
\end{align}$$
and
$$\Pr[H_0 \mid T(x) \in R] = \frac{\alpha(1-\theta)}{\alpha(1-\theta) + (1-\beta)\theta}$$
is the posterior for $H_0$ given rejection.  Your computation is incorrect for the reason that you did not apply the law of total probability correctly:  $$\Pr[H_0] = \Pr[H_0 \mid T(x) \in R]\color{red}{\Pr[T(x) \in R]} + \Pr[H_0 \mid T(x) \not\in R]\color{red}{\Pr[T(x) \not\in R]}$$ and under a Bayesian interpretation, you cannot calculate these marginal probabilities in red without specifying a prior distribution on $p$.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, the teacher asked us to sample from two binomial distribution with (p=0.5 ) and (p=0.3) thus i  i think  in my case $\theta$ is 0.5 and 1-$\theta$ is also 0.5